# How to scroll the page to the very bottom in Android Espresso?

Tags: android, testing, android-espresso

I need to check the presence of the button that is located below. To do this, scroll through the page

```
@Test
public void checkMoneyBackButton() throws Exception {

    onView(withId(R.id.btnAuthLogin)).perform(click());

    Thread.sleep(10000);
    onView(withId(R.id.etSessionKey1)).perform(typeText("1234"));
    closeSoftKeyboard();

    SystemClock.sleep(45000);

    ViewInteraction viewInteraction = Espresso.onView(withText("**** 0431"));
    viewInteraction.perform(click());

    Thread.sleep(3000);

    onView(withId(R.id.cardContainer))
            .perform(swipeUp());

    onView(withId(R.id.statementMoneyBack)).check(matches(isDisplayed()));
}
```

But using this code, I get an error:

```
 Error performing 'fast swipe' on view 'with id:...
```

Comment: Can you show more of the error? It looks like something else went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Hacky style, but should do the trick:

```
`` // Scroll down the view with for loop (as many times you need to iterate)
        for(int i=0;i<=20;i++){
            onView(withText("Use_here_any_text_from_the_view")).perform(swipeUp());
        }
``
```

Answer (score 0):

Add [Barista](https://github.com/AdevintaSpain/Barista) into your Espresso and use this command. Barista will help you  for some action in your automation (Especially if your background is not engineering like me).

```
scrollTo(R.id.far_away_widget);
scrollTo(R.string.text);
scrollTo("A widget with this text");
```